# Why does my canvas.create_text not display any text when I run it?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

I am learning how to create and use GUI and i have been at this for the last 24 hours. I am sure its just a small problem but i have no one to ask around.

This is the code.I expected that when i run the code it will display the title and word on my GUI but its not displaying. I don't have any error messages and i don't know what to change anymore.

```
from tkinter import *

BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"

window = Tk()
window.title("Flash Card")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=526)
front_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_front.png")
canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=front_image)
canvas.create_text(400, 150, text="Title", font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"))
canvas.create_text(200, 150, text="word", font=("Ariel", 40, "normal"))
canvas.config(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  I can see the "word" and "Title" text when running your code in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.14. Does your image has a black background color so that the black text is not visible on a black background?

Comment: my image background color is white. on my end, i cannot see the "word" and "title" texts at all.

Comment: The text appears fine for me on OSX. I see a greenish canvas with the text "word" and "Title", with "Title" in italics.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how its supposed to be. But I still can't see them on my OSX.

Comment: why don't you try it running in a new virtual environment...? that may resolve the issue if there is any problem in your current setup. The code is running fine in my system as well ( kubuntu linux )

Comment: It might be under the image and not on the image. If you place your image away from the text, will you see the text or not?

Comment: You use "Ariel" als your font. Does this font really exist? I only know "Arial" ...

Comment: @josephine omondi. Ur code is working. I can see light green on background.

Answer (score 2):

I also have MacBook Pro running Apple Silicon on Ventura 13.3.1(a) and I reproduce this issue.  I fixed it by changing my display from "dark" mode on to dark mode off.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

@JoeT says that it has something to do with darkmode. In darkmode the background is dark by default and the foreground (text) color is a light gray or white.

Perhaps the contrast between your chosen background color and the default text color (white?) is too low, to see the text.

Try setting the foreground / text color explicitly to a darker color, that provides good contrast.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another argument into create_text method to update text color. Probably it returns white automatically.
*fill* argument helps you to make visible your text.

> canvas.create_text(400, 150, text="Title", font=("Ariel", 40, "italic", fill='black'))

Comment: On `Python3.12.0tc`1 got an error...saying  that do you meant `'=='` or `':='` instead of  `'='`

Comment: Could you please share the complete error message? It works for Python 3.10. Maybe, there are some differences in 3.12.  Also, [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) can be reviewed for the issue:

Answer (score 0):

the fill='black' needs to happen outside of font:

```
canvas.create_text(400, 150, text="Title", font=("Ariel", 40, "italic")fill='black')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python version 3.1 follow the below command:

```
canvas_1.create_text(400,150,text="text",font=("Ariel",40,"italic") ,fill='black')
```

Don't forget to add the comma they are seen as different attributes here.